# Error in my comparator class for STL map, list, set, vector, myCompareClass

Tags: c++, stl, comparator

I am having trouble making a comparator for STL. Here is what I got so far and it is giving me an error I cannot understand what seems to be the problem. i have followed the rules to write the comparator. i don't know what seems to be the issue here.

My code is as follows

myCompareClass

```
class myCompareClass {

public:
    bool operator()(const int &p1, const int &p2)const
    {
        return p1 < p2;
    }
    
    bool operator()(const list<set<int, myCompareClass>> &p1, const list<set<int, myCompareClass>> &p2)
    {
        int sum1 = 0 , sum2 = 0 ;
        
        for (auto listIterator : p1) 
        {
            for (auto setIterator : listIterator)
            {
                sum1 += setIterator;
            }
        }

        for (auto listIterator : p2)
        {
            for (auto setIterator : listIterator)
            {
                sum2 += setIterator;
            }
        }

        return sum1 < sum2;
    }
    
    bool operator() (const map < list<set<int, myCompareClass>>, vector<int>, myCompareClass > &M1,

        const map < list<set<int, myCompareClass>>, vector<int>, myCompareClass > &M2)  const {

        int sum1 = 0 , sum2 = 0 ;

        for (auto mapIterator : M1)
        {
            for (auto listIterator : mapIterator.first)
            {
                for (auto setIterator : listIterator)
                {
                    sum1 += setIterator;
                }
            }
        }

        for (auto mapIterator : M2)
        {
            for (auto listIterator : mapIterator.first)
            {
                for (auto setIterator : listIterator)
                {
                    sum2 += setIterator;
                }
            }
        }

        return sum1 < sum2;



    }
};
```

I overloaded the << operator to help with printing it is as follows

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, const map<list<set<int, myCompareClass>>, vector<int>, myCompareClass> &obj)
{
    cout << "{  ";
    for (auto listIterator : obj)
    {
        cout << "[ ";
        for (auto setIterator : listIterator.first)
        {
            cout << "< ";
            for (auto intIterator : setIterator)
            {
                cout << intIterator << " ";
            }
            cout << "> ";
        }
        cout << "] ";

        cout << "( ";
        for (auto vectorIterator : listIterator.second)
        {
            cout << vectorIterator << " ";
        }
        cout << ")  ";
    }
    cout << "}";
    cout << endl;
    return cout;
}
```

and my main is this

```
//vectors
    vector<int> v1 = { 7,11,3 };
    vector<int> v2 = { 4,14,3 };
    vector<int> v3 = { 5,11,13 };
    vector<int> v4 = { 4,14,3 };
    vector<int> v5 = { 5,12,3 };
    vector<int> v6 = { 5,17,2 };
    vector<int> v7 = { 7,19,13 };
    vector<int> v8 = { 4,14,3 };
    vector<int> v9 = { 5,19,4 };

    //sets
    set<int, myCompareClass> g11 = { 3,5,7 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g12 = { 2,5,8 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g13 = { 3,6,11 };

    set<int, myCompareClass> g21 = { 3,5,17 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g22 = { 3,5,8 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g23 = { 1,3,6 };

    set<int, myCompareClass> g31 = { 3,4,5 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g32 = { 2,5,18 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g33 = { 2,6,13 };

    set<int, myCompareClass> g41 = { 5,6,13 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g42 = { 3,4,5 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g43 = { 3,9,11 };

    set<int, myCompareClass> g51 = { 5,7,13 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g52 = { 1,11,15 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g53 = { 3,6,8 };

    set<int, myCompareClass> g61 = { 3,4,13 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g62 = { 2,5,12 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g63 = { 2,13,16 };

    set<int, myCompareClass> g71 = { 3,5,7 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g72 = { 2,5,8 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g73 = { 3,6,11 };

    set<int, myCompareClass> g81 = { 3,5,17 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g82 = { 3,5,8 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g83 = { 1,3,6 };

    set<int, myCompareClass> g91 = { 1,7,13 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g92 = { 1,2,15 };
    set<int, myCompareClass> g93 = { 6,16,20 };

    //lists
    list<set<int, myCompareClass>> l1 = { g11,g12,g13 };
    list<set<int, myCompareClass>> l2 = { g21,g22,g23 };
    list<set<int, myCompareClass>> l3 = { g31,g32,g33 };
    list<set<int, myCompareClass>> l4 = { g41,g42,g43 };
    list<set<int, myCompareClass>> l5 = { g51,g52,g53 };
    list<set<int, myCompareClass>> l6 = { g61,g62,g63 };
    list<set<int, myCompareClass>> l7 = { g71,g72,g73 };
    list<set<int, myCompareClass>> l8 = { g81,g82,g83 };
    list<set<int, myCompareClass>> l9 = { g91,g92,g93 };

    map<list<set<int, myCompareClass>>, vector<int>, myCompareClass> m1,m2,m3;
    m1[l1] = v1;
    m1[l2] = v2;
    m1[l3] = v3;
    m2[l4] = v4;
    m2[l5] = v5;
    m2[l6] = v6;
    m3[l7] = v7;
    m3[l8] = v8;
    m3[l9] = v9;

    
    cout << m1 << endl;
```

i am trying to achieve something like this with STL

```
<> --> represents set
{} --> represents map
[] --> represents list
() --> represents vector

{  [ < 3 5 7 > < 2 5 8 > < 3 6 11 > ] ( 7 11 3 )  [ < 3 5 17 > < 3 5 8 > < 1 3 6 > ] ( 4 14 3 )  [ < 3 4 5 > < 2 5 18 > < 2 6 13 > ] ( 5 11 13 )}
```

and last but not the least the compiler error

```
Error   C2664   'bool myCompareClass::operator ()(const int &,const int) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const _Kty' to 'const std::map<std::list<std::set<int,myCompareClass,std::allocator<int>>,std::allocator<std::set<int,myCompareClass,std::allocator<int>>>>,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>,myCompareClass,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::list<std::set<int,myCompareClass,std::allocator<int>>,std::allocator<std::set<int,myCompareClass,std::allocator<int>>>>,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>>>> &' STL C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\

Error   C2056   illegal expression  STL C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\    

Error   C2664   'bool myCompareClass::operator ()(const int &,const int) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const _Keyty' to 'const std::map<std::list<std::set<int,myCompareClass,std::allocator<int>>,std::allocator<std::set<int,myCompareClass,std::allocator<int>>>>,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>,myCompareClass,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::list<std::set<int,myCompareClass,std::allocator<int>>,std::allocator<std::set<int,myCompareClass,std::allocator<int>>>>,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>>>> &'   STL C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\
    
Error   C2056   illegal expression  STL C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\
```

and yes it generates two same errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and as always thanks in advance.

Comment: please post a [mcve] (minimal!) and the compiler error

Comment: One of your operators is not `const`, but I don't know if this is source of the error if I don't see the error.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen i have edited and included the errors.

Comment: Okay. I must say the error is horribly uninformative ([gcc does much better job](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cbaoyeFQ4An8QTqE)), but the issue is indeed with the missing `const` in `operator()` which takes `list`s. After I added it, it compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/zafr1TGr5

Comment: fwiw, typically you wouldn't have one functor with many different comparisons, but rather one specific. You also don't need a custom comparator when you just want to use the elements `operator<`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks mate now it compiles. Wew they should report these errors properly. Your mind just spins while reading them.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Actually i am computing there sum, am I not doing it correctly ?

Comment: I was refering to `return p1 < p2;`. And comparing the sum on each comparsion is very inefficient, because it is recomputed on each single comparison, but in principle you need to compute it only once for every element then compare. But sorry, thats all beyond the scope of your current quesiton

Comment: Also  replace `auto` with `auto const&` in your for loops for perf boost.  Needless copies are bad.